# Android Accelerometer with better accuracy

Tags: android

I'm building an augmented reality app with POI. 
Most of the app is done but now I am trying to find a better stabilization of my sensors, in particular the Accelerometer. I have used low pass filter, but POI are still bouncing to much. The thing I was trying to do is get 5 or more readings of accelerometer and then divide it by n. That should give me better readings but i have no idea how to make it. I can make a for loop but I can't just make `for(int i=0;  i<n;  i++)`  , because **i++** should be done only when the value of accelerometer has changed. If I do it with a simple for loop, I will get an error because the loop is done faster then the sensors are changed. The thing i was looking for is a timer that will changed only when the sensors are changed too.

This is what i have done so far:

```
static final float ALPHA = 0.15f; // if ALPHA = 1 OR 0, no filter applies.


// low level pass filter, so i can get steadier reading of mobile sensors
// using only accelerometer and compass
protected float[] lowPass(float[] input, float[] output) {
    if (output == null) return input;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
       output[i] = output[i] + ALPHA * (input[i] - output[i]);
       // output[i] = input[i]*ALPHA + output[i]*(1.0f-ALPHA);
    }

    return output;
}



public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder(event.sensor.getName())
            .append(" ");
    for (float value : event.values) {
        msg.append("[").append(String.format("%.3f", value)).append("]");
    }

    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            lastAccelerometer = lowPass(event.values.clone(), lastAccelerometer);
            accelData = msg.toString();
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
            gyroData = msg.toString();
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            lastCompass = lowPass(event.values.clone(), lastCompass);
            compassData = msg.toString();
            break;
    }

    this.invalidate();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
protected float[] getMovingAvg() {
    float [] output = new float [3];
    for( int i = 0; i< moveVector.size(); i++) {
        output[0] += moveVector.get(i)[0];
        output[1] += moveVector.get(i)[1];
        output[2] += moveVector.get(i)[2];

    }
    output[0] = output[0]/moveVector.size();
    output[1] = output[1]/moveVector.size();
    output[2] = output[2]/moveVector.size();

    if(moveVector.size() >= 70) {
       moveVector.remove(0);
    }

    return output;
}
```